# Using javamail how do I send integer value 0

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a utility which creates daily reports as Excel sheets containing the file processed details the failed ones and then sends out a mail to users and this code is written in Java.

When the value of the failed files is `0` the mail has a blank sent instead of `0`.

This is the sample code

```
//sample piece of code

String bodyText = "<html>"
                    + "<body style =\"font-family: Calibri; font-size:11pt; background-color:white \">"
                    + "<table style =\"border:1px solid black;background-color:#DBE5F1;width:100%\">"
                    + "<tr style = \"background-color:#DBE5F1 ;text-align-left; font-size:11pt\">"
                    + "<br>"
                    + "&nbsp Hi All,"
                    + "</br>"
                    + "<br>"
                    + statusLine
                    + "</br>"
                    + " "
                    +"<br>"
                    + "</tr>"
                    + "<td style = \"text-align:right;width:10%;border-right:1px solid black\">"
                        + caseCreated
                    + "</td>"
                    + "<td style = \"width:10%;border-right:1px solid black;text-align:right\">"
                        + Failure
                    + "</td>"
                    +"</html>";

//and for composing the mail message 

message.setContent(bodyText, "text/html");
```

Comment: Can you post the code of how do you build the mail body and see how are you doing it?

Comment: I have just added the sample piece of code

Comment: Can you try to use toString() in the variable that returns "0" ?

Comment: I have tried converting the int value 0 to String  but still its not working ...whereas if i add 00 to the Failure it worked. So am unaware how do i send it with only a single 0

Comment: Can you try to put "&#48;" instead of "0" ?

Comment: @DeviG What is the data type of `Failure`? String or Boolean?

Comment: Try using ternary operator: `bodyText += Failure.equals("0")?"0":Failure;`

Comment: @ZainI. Its an integer....I have tried it with string as well but it didn't work.

Comment: As it's an Integer so have you tried `bodyText += Failure==0?"0":String.valueOf(Failure);` ?